# How can I login and print the next page? Python, mechanize

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a twitter login script in Python, but got stuck on one thing: how can I verify if I logged in? Because it's not clear whether it works or not.

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36')]
url = 'http://www.twitter.com/login'

def login(User, Pass):
    global url, br
    br.open(url)
    br.select_form(nr=2)
    br.form["session[username_or_email]"] = User
    br.form["session[password]"] = Pass
    br.submit()

    if br.title() == "Twitter": #doesn't work. can't scan the final page
        return True
    else:
        return False
    print br.title()
User = raw_input("User: ")
Pass = raw_input("Pass: ")
```

**The question is: How can I scan the final page after the script executed and get HTML code of it??**

Comment: Usually in this situation you would look for some element on the page that indicates whether your login succeeded or not. For example if "Welcome John Smith" is present that might indicate that you logged in successfully, or "Password incorrect" might indicate failure.

Comment: You should get a 401 unauthorized on failure, or 200 OK if login succeeds.

Comment: Also note that there are libraries that use the actual twitter API

Comment: Also, you need to call the login method.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah I understand that I need some specific elements for it, but I can't understand how to code it. I mean I can't understand how to scan the final page and determine those specific elements.

Comment: note that  print br.title() will never execute

Comment: @DanielLee I'll try it, but don't know how yet) I'm new to Python)

Comment: @cssGEEK Yeah, I noticed that. Tried to place it everywhere, never worked

Comment: @Constantine just place it before the if else

Comment: Mechanize is no longer supported, consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: @DanielLee, mechanize is much easier, but anyway, I'll try requests. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @Constantine for this application, rather use the twitter [api](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter), for any other website scraping [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) should be used.